# Error: Could not find or load main class when build Jar file

Tags: java, kotlin, jar, executable-jar

I create a Kotlin project contains some dependencies in Intelij IDEA. I want to build fat Jar file, so I can run the jar directly using the following command:

`java -jar jira-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

However, when I generate the jar i got the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class AppKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppKt
```

I believe my AppKt.class is in the jar package.

[image]

Below is my Gradle kts to build the jar file.

```
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations.compileClasspath.get().joinToString(" ") { it.name }
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "AppKt"
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    configurations.compileClasspath.get().forEach {
        from(if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it))
    }
}
```

Are there any additional configurations?

Thank you

Comment: I don't really use Gradle, but debug the value of the classpath. Not really a good idea to use the default package for your main class btw